# Poor video performance in Firefox

Tags: ati, firefox, video, google-chrome, video-player

I'd like to try to switch back from Chrome to Firefox, but there is an issue that makes it impossible. 
When I play any video with Firefox it works very slow and quality worse than in Chrome. For example, when I expand the video to fullscreen it switches very slow and the only way to exit fullscreen mode is to press Esc. But in Chrome all works fine. I've recorded a video with a demonstration of it. Please, check [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxU7g81_nhGJM05QUTdKMnJUajQ/view?usp=sharing) out.
My system is Xubuntu 14.04, video Radeon HD 7640G with fglrx drivers.

Comment: I used to be a die hard ff fan, but, ff seems to be slow. Once chromium had enough functionality I switched and never looked back. Wish they would change the default browser from ff to chromium or the the ff developers would work on performance ;)

Comment: Are you using Flash or HTML 5?

Comment: I use html5 player in both situations

Comment: Is hardware acceleration enabled in both browsers? Check the configurations.

Comment: Yes, the hardware acceleration is enabled

Comment: I installed Firefox for Windows with Wine and video works well. Can't get what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
After trying different versions of video drivers and some manipulations with settings I installed [firefox esr](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/)
I'm confused what the cause of the problem but even [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/ru/questions/1099125) didn't give any helpful advice.